# How to store URL Params, so browser remembers it when refresh or sending link to other browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, parameters, react-hooks

I am appending values from my inputs in the url and I would like that values are remembered when sharing a link or refreshing the page.

Currently I am using localStorage, which does not help to solve this issue.

URL append input value:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('contribution', count);
        params.append('employees', employees);
        params.append('savings', savings);

        history.push({ search: params.toString() });
    }, [count, employees, savings, history]);
```

Getting data form input example:

```
onChange={(changeEvent) =>
         setCount(changeEvent.target.value)
          }
```

Everything works perfect and this is the url output:

http://localhost:3000/myPage?contribution=0&employees=0&savings=0

The numbers are changing dynamically based on input, although when I want to share the link with my picked values it will refresh it back to 0s.

As I mentioned I am storing the values in localStorage, but it does nothing

```
localStorage.setItem('contribution', count);
```

How can I achieve the values being stored in URL ?

Comment: Does your application have a server/backend side?

Comment: No, it is pure React.

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.setItem('contribution', 345)
```

will store 345 as the value of contribution in `localStorage`. You can get the value as

```
localStorage.getItem('contribution');
```

Comment: I am not sure I get you, the `count` is my dynamic value coming from input - so whatever is written in input it will be written also in url `contribution=count`, where am I supposed to use the getItem ?

Comment: @Eliot the reason I used 345 instead of `count` was to exclude problems with the initialization of count. If it's properly initialized, you can replace 345 with count. But please try running the two commands above in your console first. If the second yields 345, then it works.